# Jetbrains 0xDBe: Connecting to SQL Server using Windows Authentication?

Tags: macos, sql-server-2012, windows-authentication, osx-mavericks, datagrip

Does Jetbrains 0xDBe support logging in to SQL Server with Windows Authentication?

I'm using a Mac running OS X Mavericks and attempting to connect to our corporate staging database over a VPN. Lots to go wrong there...

Right now my URL looks like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://10.11.222.333:12345
```

I've tried setting `integratedSecurity` to `true`, and also tried specifying a domain in the URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://10.11.222.333:12345;domain=MyDomain
```

No matter what, when I test the connection it just times out with this error:

```
Connection to Staging failed
java.sql.SQLException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.11.222.333, port 12345 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
    in RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)
    in RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:227)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.connect(Unknown Source)
    in LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:240)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same issues but finally found the fix by adding the domain to the jTds driver advanced settings in the 'Manage Data Sources' window.

Then using the following connection string:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<SERVER>:<PORT>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

or for connecting to a named instance:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<SERVER>;instance=<NAMED_INSTANCE>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Michael! One question ... In the jTds advanced settings, I have to enter key/value pairs. I'm assuming you entered the domain as a value here - what was the key that you used? `domain`? `host`?

Comment: No problems Josh. The key for 'Domain' is already in the list of advanced settings for jTds in 0xDbe (well at least for my instance). It's about 1/2 ways down the list. If it's not there then the key/value pairs are:
Key =  Domain

Comment: @JoshEarl, the key for Domain (and others) shows up when you download the driver. Advanced Settings are empty until then.